# Convert javascript array to Float32Array to buffer and Back

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a JS array with floats like so `[0.0028808217, -0.027968751, -0.029748825]` and I transform it to a Float32 Buffer with the following function:

```js
function toFloat32Buffer(array) {
  return Buffer.from(new Float32Array(array).buffer)
}
```

The issue I'm facing is making the conversion from the Float32 Buffer back to a JS array, so I can use the same values as the original array.

I've tried

```js
function toJSArray(buffer) {
 const newBuffer = Buffer.from(buffer) 
 const floatArray = new Float32Array(newBuffer)

 return Array.from(floatArray)
}

function toFloat32Buffer(arr) {
   return Buffer.from(new Float32Array(arr).buffer)
}

const array = [0.0028808217, -0.027968751, -0.029748825]
const bufferFromFloat32 = toFloat32Buffer(array);
const array2 = toJSArray(bufferFromFloat32);

console.log('array', array)
console.log('array2', array2)
```

`array` and `array2` have different values. How should I transform back the buffer to get the same values as the original array? I'm running this in NodeJS

Comment: Play with the [DataView() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/DataView) and use the `buffer` argument and `getFloat32` method to retrieve each of the float values from the buffer with `true` meaning the values should be interpreted accordingly. Example untested idea example perhaps (adjust accordingly): https://pastebin.com/ZJTDr3i7

Comment: I suspect that you **cannot** get back the original values. The original JavaScript numbers were 64-bit values. When you squash those into 32-bit values, you of necessity lose precision. You cannot get it back; the bits are gone.

Comment: Javascript [numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_encoding) are double-precision 64-bit. I don't think you can get back the precision that is removed converting to 32bit, short of storing it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is alternative solution. Considering using alloc

```
 function bufferToArray(buffer, size) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length / size; i++)
      arr.push(buffer.readDoubleLE(i * size));
    return arr;
  }

  function arrayToBuffer(arr, size) {
    const buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(size * arr.length);
    arr.map((val, index) => buffer.writeDoubleLE(val, size * index));
    return buffer;
  }

  let array = [0.0028808217, -0.027968751, -0.029748825];
  const size = Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT; // double-precision

  const buffer = arrayToBuffer(array, size);
  const array2 = bufferToArray(buffer, size);

  console.log(array); // [0.0028808217, -0.027968751, -0.029748825]
  console.log(array2); // [0.0028808217, -0.027968751, -0.029748825]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your `toJsArray` function to:

```
function toJSArray(buffer) {
     return new Float32Array(buffer.buffer);
}
```

The `buffer` property of buffer returns the underlying ArrayBuffer of the buffer.
But as @Matt mentioned in his comment:

> Javascript numbers are double-precision 64-bit. I don't think you can
> get back the precision that is removed converting to 32bit, short of
> storing it somewhere else. –  Matt

For more details: [buff.buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufbuffer)

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `Buffer` to a `Float32Array`, you typically need to ensure that the buffer's byte length is a multiple of 4, because each float (in a `Float32Array`) occupies 4 bytes. Here's a straightforward approach to achieve this conversion:

```js
function toJSArray(buf) {
  return new Float32Array(buf.buffer, buf.byteOffset, buf.length / Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
}
```